# Почему рекурсивная функция не останавливается?

Tags: javascript, dom

На сайте юзаю скрипт:

```
if (document.body.scrollTop < document.body.scrollHeight){
            document.body.scrollTop += 50;
            setTimeout(scroll, 100);
        } else if (document.body.scrollTop >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
            return false;
        }
    };
setTimeout(scroll, 100);
```

Скроллит страницу до конца и даже когда значения текущей позиции скролла и максимального значения сравнялись все равно не возвращает return.
Интересует именно нативный JS без фреймворков.

Comment: А что будет в `document.body.scrollTop` и `document.body.scrollHeight`, когда скролл достигнет конца страницы?

Comment: @gil9red в document.body.scrollTop должно быть значение равное либо большее чем document.body.scrollHeight

Comment: Я предполагал, что вы укажите пример значений, добавив `console.log` в код и просмотрев в консоли значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.scrollTop` не может быть больше `.scrollHeight` так как

```
scrollHeight = scrollTopMax + clientHeight
```

Правильно

```
    if (document.body.scrollTop == document.body.scrollHeight - 
                                   document.body.clientHeight)
```

Вы можете сколько угодно прибавлять 50 пикселей к scrollTop, но по достижению нижней границы страницы его значение не будет меняться, если устанавливать значение больше чем `scrollHeight - clientHeight`.

Comment: Вы говорите что `.scrollTop` не может быть больше `.scrollHeight`

И в условии `.scrollTop` больше или равен `.scrollHeight` + `.clientHeight`

Comment: @BoriHagen ну да, давно уже исправил, я там еще `scrollHeight` без буквы t на конце написал))

Comment: вот теперь замечательно, спасибо)

Comment: Тупая привычка, все пишут например `if(a==1)` а в моем коде встретишь `if(1==a)`, по невнимательности вписал `+ clientHeight` в правую часть, а хотел по-сути в левую.